# Android: Performance when calling Json file data multiple times from different classes

Tags: java, android, json, performance

I'm working for my first time with Json files as data for my app, and I have been thinking about how is the best option to save a json file to make it accessible from different classes.

It is easy, I have a JSON file with different rated for currency conversions. I need to convert the data that I show in different currencies in different modules of my app continually.

So I just want to know a good way to store my json data and not load my Json file every time that I need to check a currency rate and find a way to do it more simple, maybe as a hashmap in my BaseActivity which is extended by the rest of my activities and just call it, or a static class with all the methods related with currency rates. I also thought about save it in a sharedPreferences.

It just a question for check the opinion of more people about the best way looking for app performance to continually call data from Json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a financial expert but as far as I know currency conversion rates are applied on a daily basis. Also I have not worked on Android but the answer below is more problem-specific rather than technology specific and hence I assume that you would be able to map this to Android primitives.

I would hence design my strategy for maintaining the currency conversion rates as below:

1. Fetch the currency conversion rates the first time the app starts. Process this data and store it in memory within a HashMap for the lifetime of the app. Also, place this data into a more permanent store (e.g. **SharedPreferences**).
2. Refresh this data periodically using a service that runs once every
   24 hours fetch the updated data. Process the fetched data in a
   manner similar to above.
3. Notify the app  that the currency rates have been refreshed. In case
   the app is running it can referesh it's memory caches.

As about the class design - the hash map storing the currency exchange rates should be stored in a separate class say `CurrencyConversionRateCache`. This class exposes all method required for your activity classes to fetch conversion rates. The class also gets notified from the background service (possibly using Intents in Android) when new currency conversion rates have been downloaded. This way the cache itself is responsible for ensuring the validity of it's data keeping activity classes simple.

Hope this gives you some headstart towards solving your problem.